# How do I delete an Input from a Dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code:

```
print("Please enter your favourite foods")
a = input("Food 1: ")
b = input("Food 2: ")
c = input("Food 3: ")
d = input("Food 4: ")

food = {1:a, 2:b, 3:c, 4:d}
print(food)

Q = input("Which food would you like to remove?: ")

food.pop(Q)
sorted(food)

print(food)
```

I want the user to remove one item from the dictionary but every time they input what they want to remove I keep getting the error:

KeyError: 'whatever the user inputted'

(P.S I'm not allowed to make it into a list)

Answer (score 2):

You should convert the user input into an `int`, because the dictionary keys are `int`s. Here's an example implementation:

```
print("Please enter your favourite foods")
a = input("Food 1: ")
b = input("Food 2: ")
c = input("Food 3: ")
d = input("Food 4: ")

food = {1:a, 2:b, 3:c, 4:d}
print(food)

Q = int(input("Which food would you like to remove?: "))

food.pop(Q)
sorted(food)

print(food)
```